# Zend-Logging: Where is "'php://output"?

Tags: php, zend-framework, logging

I am a beginner with the Zend framework and want to do some logging to find errors.
I found an [example in the Zend manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.log.overview.html):

```
$logger = new Zend_Log();
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream('php://output');
$logger->addWriter($writer);
```

I wonder where I can find the `php://output`-log file after it's written? Is this a real path or is this just an example and I have to replace `php://output` with an other filename?

Comment: this is in the manual >> http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is typically used for command line interfaces and isn't particularly useful when you are executing PHP via a webserver.

For debug purposes, you could consider using `error_log` which will write to your the error log associated with your webserver.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Answer (score 4):

`php://output` isn't a file, it's a [stream](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) that allows you to print things on the screen.

From the PHP doc:

> php://output is a write-only stream that allows you to write to the
>   output buffer mechanism in the same way as print and echo.